# How to view github pages at specific commit?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm trying to view the documentation of a repository at a specific point in time. Is the github pages url hackable enough that I can specific a specific commit hash?

I can't seem to find any information on the web about this.

Comment: by documentation, are you referring to the wiki? or more like MD files within the repo itself?

Comment: Neither. I'm talking about the github pages feature that respects the `gh-pages` branch of a repository by serving it's content as a static web site viewable at a url like `http://org.github.io/repo`

Comment: if you just want to point to a html, this works: http://htmlpreview.github.io/ else, it might help a bit anyway.

Comment: One workaround for when you control the project, is to put all documentation on a RAEDME.adoc with a [table of contents](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/215), here is [an example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/79b35fb395f9f7f7621609186931408fe2f79881/README.adoc).

Answer (score 9):

Once you push your `gh-pages` branch, old files are replaced by new ones on the static files server. Only one Jekyll build snapshot allowed.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. GitHub pages only serves the *current* content of the gh-pages branch.

You can, however, clone the repo and check out the commit you are looking for locally. You might have to run Jekyll locallly, though, since ts possible to not have the actual HTML files in the gh-pages branch, but a corrrectly set up jekyll page which will get converted by GitHub on-the-fly.

Comment: It's feasible that someone could make a web service to do this automatically. Off topic, it would be neat if all or most websites had a technology like this (Wikipedia articles do), and perhaps there was a standard URI format or HTTP header one could use to get an earlier version of a site. For now, we just have services like http://archive.org/web/.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via the url but you can always clone the repo and generate the doc yourself at the commit you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am also unable to find an ideal solution. What I do at the moment is to have subdirectories under the branch `gh-pages` named for example, `v1`,`v2` etc. Then they are accessible as

```
org.github.io/repo/v1/
org.github.io/repo/v2/
...
```

This works, but there is almost 100% duplication of content with every version upgrade.